# Tensorflow ValueError: GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, valueerror

Link to my notebook with code and [error logs](https://github.com/btocoolman/Grocery-Sales-/blob/master/regressor/dnn/nn_v2.ipynb).

The GraphDef size seems to be increasing with number of steps. If done properly I don't think this should be happening. However when I change only the "display_step" variable it allows me to run some more steps until the error occurs.

Any ideas on how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is this: you're calling `get_batch_train` repeatedly in your training loop and this function creates tensors on the fly via `tf.convert_to_tensor`. Effectively this creates new nodes in your graph with each iteration, which causes OOM in the long run.

Since `train_x` and `train_y` are fed to the `session.run`, there's no need to convert them to tensors manually. So try to get rid of `tf.convert_to_tensor`.

Comment: I appreciate the help but I do need to use `tf.convert_to_tensor` in `get_batch_train`, otherwise I get an error saying that type `ndarray` is no good and that it needs a `Tensor` or `Operation`

Comment: Post your error. I'm not sure I understand the logic here

Comment: https://github.com/btocoolman/Grocery-Sales-/blob/master/regressor/dnn/nn_v2_so.ipynb

Comment: You don't need to run `get_batch_train` in `session.run`. This function provides the data that you intend to feed in, while `session.run` is for running tensors and ops, like `train_op` slightly below.